# how do I use wildcards in a gsub?

Tags: ruby

I used some brute force code to make a roman numeral converter.  I'm seeing some drying opportunities with 5s and 10s

```
 out.gsub!('IVI','V')
 out.gsub!('IXI','X')
 out.gsub!('IXLI','XL')
```

So what I'd like to do is something like...

```
out.gsub!(/'I'.'I'/,/./)
```

Where '.' is any number of characters between two 'I's

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps using [Rubular](http://rubular.com) and the [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html) documentation would be a great starting point? Wildcards are covered very well in the documentation, and Rubular makes it very easy to see what happens when you use them.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `/I(.*)I/`, which will group the string between the Is. You can access that via `\1`, producing `out.gsub!(/I(.*)I/, '\1')`.

Take a look at the documentation for regular expressions. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the captures of a regex using `\1`, `\2`, etc.:

```
outs = 'IVVVVI'
out.gsub!(/^I(.*)I$/, '\1')
# => "VVVV"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be worth trying:

```
out = 'IVVVVI'
out.tr('I','')
# => "VVVV"
```